# Copy text file content and paste it to another

Tags: python, text-files, copy-paste

I've searched for a while for the solution, so I won't bother you, but I can't find it for my problem.
I want to copy text from .txt file and paste it to another one. The problem is, I've got a bunch of these files.
I've tried to do this in python, as I have the previous script to add a new line to .txt file based on the folder name, but I just can't figure it myself.
So what I did so far based on research is:

```
import os

rootdir = 'FOLDERS'

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
        if file == 'opis.txt':
            source = '%s.txt' % subdir
            if os.path.exists(source):
                target = os.path.join(subdir, file)
                with open(source) as source_file:
                    with open(target, 'a') as target_file:
                        target_file.write(source_file.read())
```

In folder 'FOLDERS' I have .txt files that have a name as a folder containing "opis.txt" file (where I want to paste text from the text file with folder name), e.g.

```
\FOLDERS\P.1417.1969.11.txt  
\FOLDERS\P.1417.1969.11\opis.txt
```

I want to copy the line starting with "R:" (or just whole file content, as this line is the only text there) from the P.1417.1969.11.txt file and paste it to P.1417.1969.11\opis.txt
I have hundreds of files and folders with corresponding names, that's why I need a script.

EDIT: I've changed the code to the one that works.

Comment: Why don't you just copy the file and rename it?

Comment: Why doesn't your code work ? Does it output an error ?

Comment: @Isma, 'opis.txt' file has already some lines with text, so I can't just replace it.

Comment: @Magix, honestly - I wrote it in notepad++ and I am running it with double-click. I don't know how to check for errors.

Comment: If you want to add stuff to an existing file you need to open it in "a" (append) mode. When you open a file in "w" (write) mode it wipes out the old contents.

Comment: Are you trying to append text to 'opis.txt'? If you are trying to append, trying open(target,'a') ?

Comment: Apparently, it works... but, I had to change 'w' to 'a' and there was one unnecessary tabulator before "with open(source)".